# ExcelVBA copying data from one sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Have to copy data from one worksheet to another worksheet with conditions which value contains less than 100 times. Pls anyone help for the same.

EDIT: Code pasted below:

```
Sub Copycmd()

Dim sht As WorkSheet
Dim myRow As Range a=worksheets("sheet1").cells(Rows.count,1).End(xlUp).Row
Set sht = worksheets("Sheet1")

For I=2 to a
    If Application.Countif(sht.Columns(3), _ sht.Cells(I,2).Value) <100 Then
       Set myRow = sht.Rows(I) MyRow.copy 
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Activate         
       B=worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row  
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b+1,1).select 
       Activesheet.paste 
       Worksheets("sheet1").Activate 
    End If 
Next I 

Application.cutcopyMode = False 
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(1,1).select

End Sub
```

Error in the if statement

Comment: Please edit your post and include the code using the code button in toolbar.

Comment: @J.B. I don't know how to paste the code.

Comment: @J.B. I am using this app on my mobile

Answer (score 0):

Let me try this answer:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Copycmd()
Dim a, b, k As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim myRow As Range

b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
a = Worksheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Set sht = Worksheets("Sheet1")

k = 1
For I = 2 To a
    If Application.CountIf(sht.Columns(3), sht.Cells(I, 2).Value) < 100 Then
       sht.Cells(I, 2).Row.Copy
       Worksheets("Sheet2").Cells(b + k, 1).Paste
       k = k + 1
    End If
Next I

Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

This code does your countif and then paste accordingly the row after the last row of your 2nd Sheet. 
Please tell me if smth is missing or validate this as answer if it s fine :)